# Atmosphere resource inside rest resource

Tags: websocket, jersey, jax-rs, long-polling, atmosphere

How can i get the AtmosphereResource inside an existing rest resource... 
I tried this:

**atmosphere.xml**

```
<atmosphere-handlers>
    <atmosphere-handler context-root="/*"
        class-name="org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor">
        <property name="servletClass"
            value="com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer" />
    </atmosphere-handler>
</atmosphere-handlers>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxrs</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.atmos.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxrs</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.Broadcaster.supportOutOfOrderBroadcast</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Reduce memory usage by sharing ExecutorServices -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Automatically free Broadcaster objects when the last client on the 
            Broadcaster's channel disconnects -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterLifeCyclePolicy</param-name>
            <param-value>EMPTY_DESTROY</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads</param-name>
            <param-value>50</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads</param-name>
            <param-value>50</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- Any mapping -->
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**My Rest Resource**

```
@GET
@Path("/receive")
public Response receive() {
   AtmosphereResource atmosphereResource = (AtmosphereResource) req.getAttribute("org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource"); //Here the atmosphereResource is null
   // suspend the response
   atmosphereResource.suspend(timeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I am getting the **atmosphereResource** variable in the above code as null when invoking the rest resource. 
I think i might be doing something wrong either in the web.xml or atmosphere.xml. 
I want to use Atmosphere-runtime inside my existing rest resources in my application. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inject atmosphere resource using @Context AtmosphereResource              `code`                                                              @GET
@Path("/receive")
public Response receive(@Context AtmosphereResource atmosphereResource) {
   // suspend the response
   atmosphereResource.suspend(timeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   return Response.ok().build();
}                                                               `code`

Answer (score 1):

According to this [doc](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Injecting-Atmosphere%27s-Components-in-Jersey) :

Sometimes it is needed to inject Atmosphere components in a Jersey resource. The following components can be injected by using the @Context, @PathParam @QueryParam, @MatrixParam, @HeaderParam, @CookieParam, @FormParam etc. annotation

You can Inject : AtmosphereResource, Broadcaster, BroadcasterFactory

```
@Context AtmosphereResource resource
@PathParam
public String inject(@PathParam("test") Broadcaster broadcaster) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to the doc. updated the question with the answer